Proof of limit of vector valued function is equal to vector of limits of each component using open set definition
I know know how the proof of the following theorem is done by using Euclidean norm:
Ref: Prove that limit of vector valued function is equal to vector of limits of its component

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb R$ be a subset, $f : A \rightarrow \mathbb R^m$ a function and $a \in \mathbb R$ a limit point of $A$. Then
$$\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = b \iff \lim_{x \rightarrow a} f_i(x) = b_i \qquad i = 1,2,\ldots,m$$

But I don't understand how we can prove it using an arbitrary metric and using the general definition of limit (i.e. using open set and not "epsilon-delta").  Could you please tell me if this theorem works for an arbitrary metric of $\mathbb{R}^m$ and could you suggest me a sketch of the proof using open set and not "epsilon-delta" definition of limit ? Many thanks for your help!

This works for arbitrary metrics over $\Bbb R^m$, but NOT for arbitrary metrics over $\Bbb R^n$ (the codomain)

It's actually very quick to show that $\lim_{x\to a}f(x) = b \implies \lim_{x\to a}f_i(x)$ for any $i = 1,\dots,n$ if you use the fact that the component function $\pi_i:\Bbb R^n \to \Bbb R$ given by $\pi_i (x_1,\dots,x_n) = x_i$ is continuous (relative to the usual product topology over $\Bbb R^n$.

"Could you please tell me if this theorem works for an arbitrary metric of $\mathbb{R}^n$": I guess you meant $\Bbb R^m$ (the codomain). There is no $\Bbb R^n$ (the domain is $A\subseteq \Bbb R$).

It does not hold for arbitrary metrics over $\Bbb R^m$, but for those induced by some norm. If you know it for the Euclidean norm, you can just use that any norm on $\Bbb R^m$ is equivalent to that one.

@AnneBauval: Hi, thanks for your help :). I would like to just confirm with you that this theorem is true for an arbitrary metric on the domain, isn't it ?

Indeed, and even for any (non necessarily metrizable) topological space as a domain.

@AnneBauval: Hi, could you please tell me why this theorem fails for some metric on the range of the function ? I think that as long as there is a notion of "closeness" defined on BOTH the domain and range of a function, this theorem can work. So, I think that for both domain and range which are metric space, whatever metrics (one for the domain, one for the range) can do the job because they supplies the notion of closeness for both the domain and the range of a function.

The reason is that the topology (hence the "notion of closeness") on $\Bbb R^m$ depends on the metric you choose. For instance with the discrete metric, every subset is closed hence the notion of continuity for such a metric on the range is much stronger than for the Euclidean metric. The theorem holds for any topology on the domain, and any product topology on the range (induced or not by a metric). I.e.: for any topological spaces $X,Y,Z$, $(f,g):X\to Y\times Z$ is continuous iff  $f:X\to Y$ and $g:X\to Z$ are.

...and the topology on $\Bbb R^m$ induced by any norm is the product topology ($m$ times) of the usual topology on $\Bbb R$. But this doesn't hold for a topology on $\Bbb R^m$ induced by an arbitrary metric.

@AnneBauval: Hi, thanks for your comments! If i'm right, you are actually saying that because the domain is fixed (in both side of the theorem), but the codomain on the left is a Cartesian product whereas those on the right is each individual set. So to "connect" 2 parts of the theorem, a connection between the metric on the Cartesian product and each metric on individual set must be established, and as you mentioned, the metric on the Cartesian product can't be arbitrary because the topology on the Cartesian product has already a constraint by being the product topology. Am I right ? Thanks!

I agree._______

@AnneBauval: Ah ha, "point barre", I guess I know this French expression. Thanks a lot for your time answering my questions!
